# Which is better — hex escaping or octal escaping?

Tags: escaping, standards

I am writing a program that outputs arbitrary binary in a UTF-8 stream. To avoid having invalid UTF-8, I am escaping invalid characters. Should I use hex or octal escaping?

That is, should hex FFFF be escaped as this:

```
\xff\xff
```

or this:

```
\377\377
```

The first is what Python does, the second is what C does. I can't decide.

[EDIT] I need to be able to handle potentially long strings, like this:

```
SOMETHING SOMETHING\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377SOMETHING SOMETHING
```

vs.

```
SOMETHING SOMETHING\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xffSOMETHING SOMETHING
```

Comment: My answer does not rise to the level of an *answer,* since it is anecdotal, but the octal notation is traditional in C to express a single byte, as you know.  I find it easier to read the octal for a single byte just because I am used to seeing it.

Comment: I'm used to octal too, but when you have a lot it's hard. I'll do an edit.

Comment: C does this because of 7-bit ascii, Python usually runs in a unicode environment. I think this is a silly question.

Comment: This isn't silly! We have a program and I need to know which escaping standard to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many times in life, when chosing between equals,  getting past the choice is of more benefit than the value inherent in the options themselves.

Or, as a former boss of mine would say, "That's a non-problem."

Answer (score 0):

Normally people use hex for this. If you use octal, you'll have to split bytes across multiple characters, so I'd stick with hex.

Comment: I think that this answers a different question than the one asked.  Also, the assertion that "Normally people use hex for this" is inaccurate in my experience.

Comment: @thb: what world are you living in? try representing "A" in utf-8 or ascii as octal. hex: "\x41"